# Kentico v12 webpart contents are not imported properly

Tags: kentico-12

Anyone experiencing this issue? This issue only occurs when importing an update to an existing site.

I'm using Kentico v12.0.47. Below are the steps i did in importing the content.

1. Created a page and added editable text Webpart.
2. Opened the page In "Page View" and added content in the editable section. Saved changes. **- This works fine, content was properly saved and displayed.**
3. Exporting updates **- No Error**

   - Selected site and Preselect all objects.
   - Unticked All objects -> Export files
   - Unticked Global Objects -> Development -> Device Profiles
4. Importing updates **- No Error**

   - Uploaded update package
   - Selected "Preselect all items"
   - Import to **existing website**
5. Open the page in "Page View"  **- The webpart was in place but all the document contents were not imported.**

I was expecting that all the updates, webpart and its contents, were imported. There's no error message, I have no idea what's happening.

Kindly advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What license do you have? The content of the webpart is actually stored on the page's database records, therefore you need to also export the content page.

Comment: @PedroMaiaCosta currently i'm using a trial license for development purposes. I've already contacted Kentico support and they told me that it's an export/import  limitation.

Comment: Yah there you go, unfortunately that's the licensing model. But if you do move to a full license, you can then choose between import/export (all content pages) or content staging (you can select which content pages to sync).